# error:file'initramfs-3.17.8-300.fc21.x86-64.img' not found press any key to continue

Tags: fedora, boot, nvidia, initramfs

I have done what is written in this link https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide after section 2.7

I did reboot my Fedora machine, and after that, the system could not boot correctly and error below is shown on screen

> error:file'initramfs-3.17.8-300.fc21.x86-64.img' not found press any key to continue.

How can I boot correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot off a recovery media and then mount the hard-drive with the problematic OS.

cd into the directory mounted and chroot that directory. Run dracut/initramfs. Make sure that a new initramfs file is created in /boot.

Reboot the OS

Comment: i have done chroot and know i have access to boot directory but can you tell me how to run dracut/initramfs??

Comment: when i cd in boot directory and i type uname -r command it shows 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 how i can dracut/initramfs initramfs-3.17.8-300.fc21.x86-64.img ??

Comment: This article helped me to understand how to execute dracut: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-build-an-initramfs-using-dracut-on-linux